# Существительные на -нье в предложном падеже (когда и, когда е)

Tags: орфография

Существительные на -нье как правило в предложном падеже оканчиваются на "нье". Пример:

```
л'азанье - о лазанье
мяуканье - о мяуканье
(Викисловарь)
```

Однако в OpenCorpora есть много примеров таких слов, оканчивающихся в предложном падеже на "ньи".

```
о газоулавливаньи
о гноеньи
о госучрежденьи
о гуденьи
о гуляньи
```

Просто на слух, это те слова, где хочется написать "ние" вместо "нье" в именительном падеже. Но может быть есть какие-то более четкие правила. Возможно допустимы разные написания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Из Розенталя**: [VII. ПРАВОПИСАНИЕ ИМЕН СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫХ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/28.htm)

В существительных среднего рода на -ье в предложном падеже единственного числа **пишется буква е**, например: мечта о счастье, (но: в забытьи́ – под ударением).

Примеры:

А о **«гулянье»** у нее и думки не было (Н. С. Лесков).

В **молчанье** пред тобой сижу. Ночь пришла, все застыло в **молчании**.
 Но: в **молчаньи** ночи тайной – окончание И (**устаревший вариант, поэтическая речь**).

**Для справок (Розенталь)**

Написание -ние (-ание, -ение) или -нье (-анье, -енье) в суффиксах отглагольных существительных связано или **со смысловым различием, или со стилистической дифференциацией.**

**1) В смысловом отношении различаются:** варение, печение, соление [процесс, то же, что «варка», «выпечка», «засол» – варенье, печенье, соленье (результат процесса, продукт); воскресение (действие по глаголу воскресить) – воскресенье (день недели); жалование (пожалование, присуждение) — жалованье (денежное вознаграждение за работу)] и т.п.

**2) Слова книжные пишутся с суффиксом -ние,** **слова обиходные — с суффиксом -нье,** например: а) воспитание, достижение, явление; б) барахтанье, беганье, воркованье, дерганье, кваканье, кряхтенье, тявканье, фырканье, харканье, хихиканье, чавканье, чириканье, шиканье, щелканье.

Comment: "В молчаньи ночи тайной" разве ударение не на "а"?

Comment: Ударение, конечно, на А, просто в старой орфографии  допускалось окончание ЬИ, поэтому оно до сих пор встречается в поэзии: "О, долго буду я, в молчаньи ночи тайной, Коварный лепет твой, улыбку, взор, взор случайный ... Из мыслей изгонять, и снова призывать".

Comment: Решил проверить себя, правильно ли я, не задумываясь тогда об окончании, написал "Всё в исполнень**и**".  И первой ссылкой попал на наш же сайт, на этот вопрос и ваш ответ. О том, что в поэзии допускается И в предложном падеже, узнал раньше (опять же из информации нашего сайта). Захотелось узнать, зачем и почему И в полной форме слова (о желани**и**) меняется на Е в редуцированной (о желань**е**). А копаться самому лень :)  Я не прошу ответа. В стихе для ритма мне нужна была "усеченная" форма, в прозе написал бы полную с ИИ – эта последняя И и осталась в итоге.

Comment: У меня хотите проверить? А я тоже не знаю, это вопрос для форума :)   История орфографии, историческая грамматика-фонетика, и всё такое. Я тоже обратила внимание на ваше "в молчаньи", примерила сюда "в молчанье", но мне форма показалась грубой, совсем не поэтической. Почему - загадка!